# Typesetting Math and Text Commands

Tags: symbols, superscripts

In your opinion, what is the best way to place things like symbols next to names, if some symbols are meant for text and you have to be in mathmode to use the exponent functionality? What is the command for that specific `cross` at the end of the name? I checked and found `\Cross` of the [marvosym](http://ctan.org/pkg/marvosym) package, but it was much more **bold** and shorter to my eyes then the one below.

Also a slightly better title would be appreciated if someone thinks of one.

[image: names]

Comment: `\textsuperscript{\textdagger}`

Comment: @night owl  Try dagger for the symbol They are all footnote marks.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for footnotes or endnotes.

You can obtain the symbol with `\dagger`

Comment: Thanks. But I think it seems to be some sort of a cross rather than dagger, i.e., not sharp end or round side pointers. You can view this by zooming your screen view maybe 500x

Comment: It depends on the font how exactly the symbol looks like.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not necessary to go into math mode (explicitly) in order to typeset text symbols: the relevant command is `\textsuperscript`.

For example, your authors can be

```
Jun Zheng\textsuperscript{\textdagger},
Suhail Saquib\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered},
...
```

and the first affiliation

```
\makebox[0pt][r]{\textsuperscript{\textdagger}}Department of
  Electrical Engineering ...
```

(the zero width box is to avoid the superscript participating in the centering, which is usually what's desired).

You might want to have a look at the package [authblk](http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) for automating this kind of author and affiliation typesetting.

Comment: Strange enough, standard LaTeX does not define the similar `\textsubscript` command.  A couple of times a customer wanted it, and I ought to define it by the obvious modification of `\textsuperscript`

Comment: @Boris `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` provides `\textsubscript`

Comment: Thanks a lot again for those nifty commands `textsuperscript` and now `textsubscript` and the package `fixltx2e` (just found out about that one). I don't know how much grief LaTeX caused me when wanting to do things like this outside the math-mode environment. This will shed major minutes of debugging off my coding time. LoL `:)`